# How can I remove NaN values from the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataframe and how can I remove NaN valued columns from it?
[image]

Comment: [`df.dropna(axis='columns', how='all')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recommend you to read "[How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)" for future questions or even for this want if you want to add more details. You should provide what have you tried.

Then, try to search in your preferred searcher (eg. DuckDuckGo, Google, etc.) your doubt before to ask, because it is possible that someone already solved it, in StackOverflow or other website. And not forget to read the documentation of the package you are using, in this case, [Pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/), which is very complete and interesting. Documentation should always being the first place to search, at least with the packages well-documented.

About your problem, you can solve your problem with `pandas.DataFrame.dropna()`, [check this method in the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html), where you can see examples. Although the basic use is very simple. If you dataframe is named `df`, then you can do:

```
df.dropna(axis='columns')
```

There are a many options to achieve what you want with `df.dropna()`, but as you have not provided an example I really don't know if you want to remove where there is NaN in an entire column or if there is just one, or two...

I also recommend you to read "[How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)".